# "Less for more" or "More for less"?

Tags: word-choice, slogan

I don't know if this belongs more to [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Pardon me if it does.

---

Which is more suitable for kind of a slogan:

`Less for more` - The word `less` refers to the prices and money, `more` refers to the quality and amount of the product. Can be understud as that `less` refers to quality and amount of the product and `more` refers to prices and money.

`More for less` - Same as above, just inverted.

---

Which would be the clearer one, that more likely wouldn't be misunderstud?

Comment: My gut reaction is that "more for less" is going to be better understood, with the missing assumptions being: "(You get) more for less (money)". However, either way it's going to be unclear unless you specify at least one of the assumptions, for example "Less (money) for more" or "(You get) more for less".

Comment: This is completely subjective. FWIW, *more for less* is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=less+for+more%2Cmore+for+less&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cless%20for%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20for%20less%3B%2Cc0) than *less for more*, but without context, neither really means anything specific. And *with* context, the intended meaning will normally be obvious.

Comment: I second "more for less." Mostly because I've heard this as a store's slogan before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*More for less* definitely sounds like a better bargain.

*Less for more* sounds like the old joke "a bargain at half the price."

I would say the reason has to do with which of these two phrases sounds more natural:

> *Three for a dollar.*
>
> *A dollar for three.*

To my ear, the first does.  I expect the goods to come first and the price to come second.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect an advertisement to advertise what it's selling before it advertises what it costs.

- 5 eggs for a dollar

... not ...

- A dollar for 5 eggs

Perhaps that's because a vendor would offer eggs, instead of asking for dollars.

Therefore, they should advertise "more for less".